# can't read quoted field with gocsv

Tags: csv, go

I have a csv response that comes from an endpoint that I don't control and I'm failing to parse its response because it has quotes. It looks something like this:

```
name,id,quantity,"status (active, expired)"
John,14,4,active 
Bob,12,7,expired
```

to parse this response I have created the following struct:

```
type UserInfo struct {
Name     string `csv:"name"`
ID       string `csv:"id"`
Quantity string `csv:"quantity"`
Status   string `csv:"status (active, expired)"`
}
```

I have tried using

```
Status   string `csv:""status (active, expired)""`
Status   string `csv:'"status (active, expired)"'`
```

but none seem to be helpful, I just can't access the field Status when I use `gocsv.Unmarshal`.

```
var actualResult []UserInfo
err = gocsv.Unmarshal(in, &actualResult)

for _, elem := range actualResult {
    fmt.Println(elem.Status)
    }
```

And I get nothing as as response.

https://go.dev/play/p/lje1zNO9w6E here's an example

Comment: You don't need to have the quotes in the field name, you just have invalid tags with an extra space. Run `go vet`.

Comment: I don't think I understood, can you expand it a little bit more?

Comment: @hcp `csv: "status"` => `csv:"status"`. If you'd run `go vet` on your source code then it would see a warning telling you that your struct tags have an unconventional (invalid) format.

Comment: oh this is not the real problem, in the example I'm trying to solve the space doesn't exist. This was just silly me trying to replicate without paying much atention to details.

Comment: Then please post a [mre], the csv and type shown works as expected: https://go.dev/play/p/JLscl4mFxwU

Comment: Note also that if the brackets `[` and `]` are part of the actual response then that could be your actual problem, trying to parse non-csv content with the incorrect tool.

Comment: Your tag now contains a `,`, which is used to delimit tag values. Perhaps the library you are using has a way to work around that, or seeing how csv is a simple encoding, skip trying to use struct tags and use `encoding/csv`?

Comment: @JimB can you expand on that a bit? not sure if I understand how to not use struct tags and use encoding

Comment: CSV headers are just a normal entry used as column names by convention. You can read each row in to a slice of strings and process the data however you want with https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv

Comment: This bug been reported here https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv/issues/235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need third party package like `gocsv` (unless you have specific usecase) when it can be done easily with Go's builtin [`encoding/csv`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv).

You just have to ignore first line/record which is `csv header` in your endpoint's response.

```
csvReader := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(csvString))

records, err := csvReader.ReadAll()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var users []UserInfo

// Iterate over all records excluding first one i.e., header
for _, record := range records[1:] {
    users = append(users, UserInfo{Name: record[0], ID: record[1], Quantity: record[2], Status: record[3]})
}

fmt.Printf("%v", users)
// Output: [{ John 14 4 active } { Bob 12 7 expired}]
```

Here is [working example on Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/fezhSBkDR3L) based on your use case and sample string.

Comment: Hi, I can’t speak for OP but the ability to define our CSV record as metadata on the struct is very useful, and takes away a good amount of “interpret/transform” code.

Answer (score 1):

I simply don't think gocarina/gocsv can parse a header with a quoted comma.  I don't see it spelled out anywhere in the documentation that it cannot, but I did some digging and there are clear examples of commas being used in the "CSV annotations", and it looks like the author only conceived of commas in the annotations being used for the purposes of the package/API, and not as part of the column name.

If we look at [sample_structs_test.go](https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv/blob/master/sample_structs_test.go) from the package, we can see commas being used in some of the following ways:

- in metadata directives, like "omitempty":

  ```golang
  type Sample struct {
      Foo  string  `csv:"foo"`
      Bar  int     `csv:"BAR"`
      Baz  string  `csv:"Baz"`
      ...
      Omit *string `csv:"Omit,omitempty"`
  }
  ```
- for declaring that a field in the struct can be populated from multiple, different headers:

  ```golang
  type MultiTagSample struct {
      Foo string `csv:"Baz,foo"`
      Bar int    `csv:"BAR"`
  }
  ```

  You can see this in action, [here](https://go.dev/play/p/u5Qg2k6Eho8).

FWIW, the official encoding/json package has [the same limitation](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal), and they note it (emphasis added):

> The encoding of each struct field can be customized by the format string stored under the "json" key in the struct field's tag. The format string gives the name of the field, possibly followed by a **comma**-separated list of options. The name may be empty in order to specify options without overriding the default field name.

and

> The key name will be used if it's a non-empty string consisting of only Unicode letters, digits, and ASCII punctuation except quotation marks, backslash, and **comma**.

So, you may not be able to get what you expect/want: sorry, this may just be a limitation of having the ability to annotate your structs.  If you want, you could file a bug with gocarina/gocsv.

In the meantime, you can just modify the header as it's coming in.  [This is example](https://go.dev/play/p/oqOfI2SKqQ1) is pretty hacky, but it works: it just replaces "status (active, expired)" with "status (active expired)" and uses the comma-less version to annotate the struct.

```golang
endpointReader := strings.NewReader(sCSV)

// Fix header
var bTmp bytes.Buffer
fixer := bufio.NewReader(endpointReader)
header, _ := fixer.ReadString('\n')
header = strings.Replace(header, "\"status (active, expired)\"", "status (active expired)", -1)
bTmp.Write([]byte(header))
// Read rest of CSV
bTmp.ReadFrom(fixer)

// Turn back into a reader
reader := bytes.NewReader(bTmp.Bytes())

var actualResult []UserInfo
...
```

I can run that and now get:

```
active 
expired
```